# onServiceConnected never called in Android with APK expansion files

Tags: android, android-service, apk-expansion-files

I'm using the sample downloader activity from Google in order to get the APK expansion files, and everything works perfectly, except that it shows no progress or notification to the user.
I looked into it a little bit more and realized that my `onServiceConnected` is never called, so the service is never bound and there's no progress shown to the user, as well as there's a crash happening when pressing the "Pause Download" button since it can't stop the service.

Here's the implementation, but it's the same one than the sample:

```
@Override
    public void onServiceConnected(Messenger m) {
        mRemoteService = DownloaderServiceMarshaller.CreateProxy(m);
        mRemoteService.onClientUpdated(mDownloaderClientStub.getMessenger());
    }
```

Any idea why this could happen?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Have you got any solution? I am also stucked at same place.

Comment: unfortunately I never got a solution and we have to revert the changes and think of another approach.

Comment: After a code review I got my issue. I was passing my activity instance instead of instance of service.

Comment: @Ankit I'm passing service (`DownloaderClientMarshaller.CreateStub
                (this, ExpansionDownloaderService.class)`) but no luck

Comment: @SrikarReddy i have done it 3 years back and now APIs might have got changed a lot.